# How to get drupal 7 default file upload directory?

Tags: files

I have trouble to get the upload directroy from drupal. Is there some function returning the relative or absolute path?

Comment: Consider using wrappers (`public://`, `private://`, etc to avoid any folder conflicts. Take advantage of Drupal 7 :) )

Comment: I know that this works with image_style_url(uri) but i want to pass it to javascript as a variable for futher processing...thanks though

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This information is saved in Drupal's variables table. Use the `variable_get` function to get this information, passing in the name of the correct variable:

- **Public Filesystem Location**: `variable_get('file_public_path', conf_path() . '/files');`
- **Private Filesystem Location**: `variable_get('file_private_path');`

If you want the temporary upload directory use `variable_get('file_temporary_path');` If you want to determine the system specific upload directory, regardless of the actual site configuration use the `file_directory_temp` function.

`variable_get('file_public_path', conf_path() . '/files');` will pull the default path for you in case it has not been modified or explicitly set by the site administrator.

Comment: hmm in my case variable_get('file_public_path') is empty...do i have to call it within a hook or so?

Comment: @Jurudocs Use this instead: `variable_get('file_public_path', conf_path() . '/files');` Basically, it pulls the default path for you in case it has not been modified or explicitly set by the site administrator.

Comment: @zhilevan Check your file permissions on that directory.

Comment: This only gives the relative path which seems less useful than the absolute path. I like the `drupal_realpath` solution below. Seems more legit.

Answer (score 11):

To get the absolute file system paths use `drupal_realpath` [(Drupal API)](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21file.inc/function/drupal_realpath/7) instead of `file_create_url`:

```
drupal_realpath('public://'); 
// returns e.g. /var/www/drupal/sites/default/files

drupal_realpath('private://');
// returns e.g. /var/www/drupal/sites/default/files_private
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use these functions to get a valid url from a relative uri:

```
file_create_url('public://');
file_create_url('private://');
```

They return the path to the public or private folders.