# How to find the src for an uploaded file?

Tags: files

I'm working on a simple module to create a field formatter that uses FlowPlayer to display videos.

My problem is that I need the src path to my uploaded video as a variable in my `.tpl.php` file.

Using `hook_field_formatter_view()` I can get the file's fid, filename, and uri but I don't know of a good way to turn that into an src value.

My video is at:

```
drupal/sites/default/files/MY_VIDEO_NAME.mp4
```

My .tpl.php file is at:

```
drupal/sites/default/modules/custom/flowplayer/flowplayer_video.tpl.php
```

I could just hard code the path and then just use the file name (`../../../files/$filename`) but that seems like a bit of a hack and it would break as soon as I started moving files around. I've spent several hours now, hunting around, and I think I'm missing something obvious.

Thanks

Comment: This could help: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/61028/how-to-get-drupal-7-default-file-upload-directory. Otherwise, the file.inc API would be the place to look: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21file.inc/7

Comment: I think https://drupal.org/node/837794  is what you're looking for.    Relevant Drupal functions: `file_create_url()`, `drupal_real_path()`, `parse_url()`.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using file_create_url() function. It wasn't quite what I wanted but it did do the trick.